# Measurement API in Swift (Ignore Locale) When Formatting Output

Tags: ios, swift

I have a convert function which returns the Measurement to the user. This allows me to covert between different units. The problem is when I print the value using the formatted function, it always shows as ft, since my locale is set that way. How can I make sure that it shows the correct formatting for units like m for meters or cm for centimeters etc.

```
extension Double {
    
    func convert(from: UnitLength, to: UnitLength) -> Measurement<UnitLength> {
        let measurement = Measurement(value: self, unit: from)
        return measurement.converted(to: to)
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let distance: Double = 100    
   
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // formatted always prints out the result as locale aware
            // how can I make it print centimeters or meters etc
            Text(distance.convert(from: UnitLength.meters, to: UnitLength.centimeters).formatted())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `.formatted` property of your measurement then you get

> a locale-aware string representation of a measurement

You will need to create your own `MeasurementFormatter` and specify the [`.providedUnit`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurementformatter/unitoptions/1642063-providedunit) option

This will ignore your locale and format the measurement using the unit of the measurement (in this case cm)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let distance: Double = 100 

    let formatter: MeasurementFormatter = {
        let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
        formatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit
        return formatter
    }()   
   
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // formatted always prints out the result as locale aware
            // how can I make it print centimeters or meters etc
            Text(self.formatter.string(from:distance.convert(from: UnitLength.meters, to: UnitLength.centimeters)))
        }
    }
}
```